# C# - Cursor position (all screen)

Tags: c#, cursor-position

help me please! :)
My program should get cursor position **(all screen) every ~50 ms** and them **write in text Box**.
How it make?

Example:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Text = e.X.ToString();
   textBox2.Text = e.Y.ToString();
}
```

but we get position **only in window**

*it's really do?*

Comment: This is the most uncomprehendible post I've ever, **ever** seen.

Comment: Have you [googled](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&site=webhp&source=hp&q=get+mouse+position+in+screen+c%23&oq=get+mouse+position+in+screen+c%23&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30l5j0i22i10i30j0i22i30j0i22i10i30j0i22i30l2.868.21376.0.21542.43.28.2.10.12.0.402.6149.1j7j4j10j1.23.0...0.0.0..1c.1.16.hp.RSgjyvRkKzE) your question?

Comment: be nice........

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use `Cursor.Position` :

```
   textBox1.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString();
   textBox2.Text = Cursor.Position.Y.ToString();
```

btw , welcome to SO , please Consider searching the site before asking questions.

and for getting these result every 50 ms you need to use `Timer`
, here's a tutorial for `Timer` : [C# Timer Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer)

**Update :**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer t1 = new Timer();
        t1.Interval = 50;
        t1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        t1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = Cursor.Position.Y.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: how get and write position every 50ms? I want to know it more.

Comment: you need to use `timer` for that , you may find plenty tutorials for that by searching google

Comment: I'll update my answer and add a timer to it for you

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(50);
            myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
            myTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Cursor.Position.X.ToString();
        }  ?how edit textBox in _timer_Elapsed?

Comment: Hurray!! Thank you very much!!! ^^